# Wont be able to change custom position of Tooltip rather its default position top, left, right, bottom in Kendo - Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

[I need my tooltip like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WulFW.png)

[and I am getting like this! You can see the image has shadow type box because there is a class k-popup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxByF.png)

Now My code is like this

```css
.k-tooltip {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  width:500px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px !important;
  background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(22,34,58,0.11) !important;
  color: white !important;
  left:40%;
  
}


.k-callout-s {
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(22,34,58,0.11) !important;
  
}

.k-tooltip-content{
  color: #3E3935;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<ng-template #alarmdes let-anchor>
   {{anchor.nativeElement.getAttribute('dataTooltip')}}
</ng-template>
<div  class="alarm" 
      showOn="click"
      kendoTooltip    
      [tooltipTemplate]="alarmdes"
      filter=".alarmdescp">
<kendo-grid-column field="alarmId" title="Alarm Type" [width]="250">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem> 
   <span>{{dataItem.alarmName}}</span>
    <span  class="alarmdescp" [attr.dataTooltip]="dataItem.description">
      <img src="../../assets/images/info.svg" alt="i"                                                  style="width:12px;height:12px;margin:10px;"/>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid-column>
```

Also tooltip is not working on the showOn ="hover" on mobile browser. It is accessible by doing click.

Also, wont be able to change the css explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can achieve by using

```css
.k-tooltip-wrapper {
  left : 30px !important;   //you can customize ur pos by using this class
}

.k-tooltip {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  width:500px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #0082c9 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(22,34,58,0.11) !important;
  color:#0082c9 !important;  
}

.k-callout-s {
  color: #0082c9 !important;
}

.k-tooltip-content{
  color: white;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
 
import { ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector : your selector,
templateUrls : your template,
styleUrls: your style url,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```